# Android app with default top & bottom padding

Tags: android

We have an android device with default header & footer. As per need, our app must fix between this header & footer. So all the pages, modals, popups of the app must have top & bottom padding to fit within that container. In a clear way, is it possible to set padding to the whole android app? (Ref: Below image)

[image: Mockup]

Comment: can't you create / modify some default theme in the `styles.xml` and set desired padding for this theme and use it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use FrameLayout inside the parent activity and can set the Top and bottom margin and then load all your UI screens as Fragments inside that FrameLayout. this will resolve your issue. let me know if it meets your requirements.